# Pop Up in Angular and Getting Value from PopUP

Tags: angular, angular-material, popup

On click Save Button, PopUp should open by `let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.callAPIDialog);` and I need `<textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" formControlName="description"></textarea>` and submit Button in the pop up. And On clicking Submit, Value to be transferred same Function.

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you dialog add

```
(click)="dialogRef.close(value)"
```

and you will get it here

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`); // which will be value
})
```

please check this link for more https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

[image]

Comment: How make TextArea Required ?

Comment: `<textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" formControlName="description" required></textarea>`

Comment: set something to value variable or pass string for now dialogRef.close('value')

Comment: added in answer

Comment: may be callAPIDialog.value is undefined

Comment: try this <ng-template #callAPIDialog> <textarea #name matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" formControlName="description" required></textarea> <button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close(name.value)">Submit</button> </ng-template>

Comment: update no thanks button as   `<button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>`